# AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, exception, object, properties

Python (2.6) seems to be derping for no reason, can anyone see a problem with this code?

```
class DB ():
    def doSomething (self, str):
        print str

class A ():
    __db = DB()

    @staticmethod
    def getDB ():
        return A.__db

    db = property(getDB)


A.db.doSomething("blah")
```

Fails with the exception:

> AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'doSomething'

It was my understanding that a property would automatically run its getter when accessed, so why is it complaining about a property object, and why isn't it finding my clearly available method?

Comment: What Python version? If using Python 2.x, you'll need to build classes inheriting from `object`...

Comment: @JonClements -- Good eye!  and it appears that OP is using python2.x because OP uses `print str`

Comment: 2.6, classes work fine without inheriting from object. Do i need to do this just for properties to work?

Comment: @ben Unless you have a very good reason - all your objects should inherit from `object`

Comment: Sorry Jon, i forgot to add the staticmethod decorator in my example. I wont be instantiating this class so inheriting from object will have no effect. Regardless, what are the benefits of inheriting from object?

Comment: @Ben For one thing, properties only work with "new-style" classes which inherit from object. There are other features like that too. "Old-style" classes which don't inherit from object are *long* deprecated, and are only still around for ancient backwards compatibility concerns. They are gone in Python3, where everything inherits from object automatically. In Python2 you should consider the standard recipe for creating a class to be `class Name(object)` (unless you have a base class already, of course).

Comment: Yep, i was unaware of having to inherit from object until this point. I've refactored my code to reflect this now, although i'm still unsure what problems are actually caused by *not* inheriting from object, apart from it's "bad form", and properties don't work (which i'm not going to bother with anyway).

Comment: I believe certain special methods only work for newstyle classes, and `super` only works with them. I'm sure there are a few other cases. They are also supposedly much more efficient. You could almost certainly find more information if you were interested by googling for "python new style class".

Comment: I guess there's a bunch of magic behind the scenes, no reason not to use them! Admittedly i'm not as experienced with Python as with most other languages i program with so i guess i never came across an instance of this until now! Good it was flagged up before i ran into a bunch of other problems down the line :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to needing to inherit from `object`, properties only work on instances.

```
a = A()
a.db.doSomething("blah")
```

To make a property work on the class, you can define a metaclass. (A class is an instance of a metaclass, so properties defined on the metaclass work on the class, just as properties defined on a class work on an instance of that class.)

Comment: This is a static class, i wont be creating any instances. I assume this also makes inheriting from object pointless?

Comment: Easiest solution, assuming you don't need to be able to subclass this "static" class, is to just do `A = A()` right after the class definition.  You then have one instance of the class upon which methods can be called. (It is possible, of course, to create new instances using `type()`, but this should be warning enough not to do that. Or use a metaclass.)

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to keep it static and i don't think it's worth implementing a metaclass just for largely superfluous properties, so i'll just ditch them altogether. Shame since on face value they seemed quite neat, if not very useful.

Comment: You don't need properties,though.

Comment: True. I'm working on an API and figured it would be nice to provide properties and getters, depending on the programmers preference.

Comment: If you're using the class simply as a namespace, which seems to be what you mean by "static," it doesn't matter much whether the container is actually a class...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using classes correctly. A class is (normally) two things:

1. A factory for creating a family of related objects
2. A definition of the common behaviour of those objects

These related objects are the **instances** of the class. Normal methods are invoked on *instances* of the class, not on the class itself. If you want methods that can be invoked from the class, without an instance, you need to label the methods with `@classmethod` (or `@staticmethod`).

However I don't actually know whether properties work when retrieved from a class object. I can't check right now, but I don't think so. The error you are getting is that `A.db` is retrieving the property object which defines the property itself, it isn't "evaluating" the property to get `A.__db`. Property objects have no `doSomething` attribute. Properties are designed to be created in classes as descriptions of how the *instances* of those classes work.

If you did intend to be working with an instance of A, then you'll need to create one:

```
my_a = A()
my_a.db.doSomething("blah")
```

However, this will also fail. You have not correctly written `getDB` as any kind of method. Normal methods need an argument to represent the instance it was invoked on (traditionally called `self`):

```
def getDB(self):
    ...
```

Static methods don't, but need a decorator to label them as static:

```
@staticmethod
def getDB():
    ...
```

Class methods need both an argument to receive the class they were invoked on, and a decorator:

```
@classmethod
def getDB(cls):
    ...
```

Comment: It does have a staticmethod decorator. And there are many more ways to use classes than just the two you suggested. You didn't really answer the question here, just stated some obvious facts. I figured the property wasn't being evaluated correctly, which formed the basis of my question...

Comment: @It wasn't there when I wrote the answer. You appeared not to know that the property wasn't being evaluated, since you were asking "why isn't it finding my clearly available method?" rather than "why isn't python calling getDB?". It looked very much like the question sprang from some very fundamental misconceptions about classes in python; glad to learn that wasn't the case. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I figured since you answered that much longer after the others you'd seen the edit, sorry about that. Either way your answer may help others that stumble across it so not to worry! I'm still not really sure why an instance of the class is required for properties to be evaluated however?

Comment: @Ben For a definitive answer you'd have to ask the original designers. My guess would be that they considered that use case to be tangential, since most properties *need* an instance and will fail if you try to evaluate them without one. And if you couldn't retrieve the underlying property object from the class there'd be no way to get to it at all, since you can never guarantee that whatever it returns will have a `__property__` special attribute (or whatever).

Comment: @Ben Slowness is because I'm on my phone.

Comment: Makes sense i suppose. It would seem Python never intended to have purely static classes (judging from most of the material i've come across online). I haven't heard any convincing arguments against them though, and in my particular case i prefer it to creating a singleton and having to pass that instance all over the shop, as it were.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21103/discussion-between-ben-and-ben)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need getters in Python:

```
class B(object):
    def do_something(self, str):
        print str

class A(object):
    db = B()

A.db.do_something("blah")
```

(I also PEP8:ed the code)

Comment: This is not the same code. db is no longer private. A is no longer static. And you're right, i don't *need* getters, but i want them.

Comment: @Ben: A is still static, it has not been instantiated. B never was private, there is no such thing as "private" objects in Python. All you did was namespace mangling.

Comment: True, but it's now less obvious with inheritance and a lack of static methods, but i appreciate this is all just theory. And yes again true, but it's Python's equivalent and i think the difference here is negligible.

Comment: @Ben: You don't *need* getters, but you want them... Have you considered what you want them *for*? What you expect to achieve by using them? You also do not appear to need a class *at all* if you are not instantiating nor subclassing it, since you're just using it as a glorified module.

Comment: The code in this example is a simple extraction based off my original problem. There is scope for many of my member vars to require additional processing, hence the getters. Whilst this wont apply to all member vars, my classes form modules within an API and i'd like to keep them consistent.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, but the API didn't change. I just skipped the getter. And the difference between private methods as they exist in say Java, and Pythons namespace mangling is not negligible. In fact, the *similarities* are negligible.

Comment: But the API did change. Now you access some members through a getter, and others without. I understand the processes involved with private variables and name mangling share little similarity, but this is besides the point. They are both used to achieve the same goal, so the whole argument is purely academic. Anticipating your response: since the notion of truly private variables within Python doesn't exist, there is no need to include that in your reasoning.

Comment: @Ben: If you use a getter or not is not an API change, that's an implementation detail. No, the name mangling and private variables are not used to achieve the same goal.