# Python properties and string formatting

Tags: python, string, properties, formatting

I was under the impression python string formatting using .format() would correctly use properties, instead I get the default behaviour of an object being string-formatted:

```
>>> def get(): return "Blah"
>>> a = property(get)
>>> "{a}!".format(a=a)
'<property object at 0x221df18>!'
```

Is this the intended behaviour, and if so what's a good way to implement a special behaviour for properties (eg, the above test would return "Blah!" instead)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`property` objects are descriptors.  As such, they don't have any special abilities unless accessed through a class.

something like:

```
class Foo(object):
     @property
     def blah(self):
         return "Cheddar Cheese!"

a = Foo()
print('{a.blah}'.format(a=a))
```

should work. (You'll see `Cheddar Cheese!` printed)

Comment: And that's where I got confused, used property() inside a class instead of the property decorator. Thanks!

Comment: Also note that properties can only be accessed on instances. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13867254/884640

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is basically the same as if you just did:

```
>>> def get(): return "Blah"
>>> a = property(get)
>>> print a
```

If you want `"Blah"` just call the function:

```
>>> def get(): return "Blah"
>>> a = property(get)
>>> "{a}!".format(a=a.fget())
```

Answer (score 1):

Python properties do interop well with .format(). Consider the following example:

```
>>> class Example(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self._x = 'Blah'
...     def getx(self): return self._x
...     def setx(self, value): self._x = value
...     def delx(self): del self._x
...     x = property(getx,setx,delx, "I'm the 'x' property.")
...
>>>
>>> ex = Example()
>>> ex.x
'Blah'
>>> print(ex.x)
'Blah'
>>> "{x.x}!".format(x=ex)
'Blah!'
```

I believe your problem stems from your property not being part of a class. How are you actually using properties that they aren't working with .format()?

Comment: Note that here `format` isn't calling your property.  Python is calling your property to resolve the object that it is going to pass to `format`.  That's just a nitpick, but it is a little different than `'{x.x}'.format(x=ex)` where the property's getter gets called inside the `format` function/method.