# Define class variable with instance of another class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm have the following class set:

```
class External(object):

    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def foo():
        print('something')

class Parent(object):

    shirt_color = ''
    shoes_color = ''
    external_class = External(shirt_color, shoes_color)

class SouthParent(Parent):

    shirt_color = 'white'
    shoes_color = 'blue'
```

Because SouthParent is a children of Parent and the class variables shirt_color and shoes_color are redefined in the SouthParent class, the expected args that External() would receive should be ('white', 'blue') but the instead it receives ('','')

This is defined this way, to be used in the terminal like SouthParent.external_class.foo() like Django Model ( User.objects.all() )

Comment: At the time `External` is actually called, `shirt_color` and `shoes_color` are not class variables *at all*; they are simply local variables in the body of the `class` statement that will be added to the class's dictionary once the metaclass actually creates `Parent`.

Answer (score 1):

You never define `external_class` on `SouthParent`, so accessing that attribute uses the `external_class` from `Parent`, where it was defined as `External('', '')`.

If you want to have it construct `external_class` based on the class attributes, you can use a property:

```
class Parent(object):

    shirt_color = ''
    shoes_color = ''

    @property
    def external_class(self):
        return External(self.shirt_color, self.shoes_color)
```

If it should be the *same* `External` instance each time, do it this way:

```
class Parent(object):

    shirt_color = ''
    shoes_color = ''

    _external_class = None

    @property
    def external_class(self):
        if self._external_class is None:
            self._external_class = External(self.shirt_color, self.shoes_color)
        return self._external_class
```

Comment: Yes but I redefine the class variables that are called in External, do you have an alternative ?

Comment: Redefining the class variables won't do anything... why would it? Python doesn't magically remember how each value was constructed and redo the construction when any of its components change

Comment: can't use `@property` decorator if class isn't instantiated [like in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867172/attributeerror-property-object-has-no-attribute)

Comment: Well, yes. you need to instantiate the class. That's what classes are for, after all. I thought that would go without saying...

Comment: I'm not sure if you are familiar with Django, but the Models can be used to instantiate `User(email='asda@asd.com').save()` or `User.objects.all()` that is my purpose with this code, to replicate this

Comment: If you need property behavior on a class, you could use a property on its metaclass... but at that point you'd naturally start wondering why.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had spent hours looking for this solution and my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution: (with help of @kindall)

Use Python metaclass

```
class External(object):
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def foo():
        print('something')

class ParentMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        if attrs['shirt_color'] and attrs['shoes_color']:
            attrs['external_class'] = External(attrs['odoo_model'],attrs['cache_name'])

        return super(ParentMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Parent(metaclass=ParentMeta):

    shirt_color = ''
    shoes_color = ''         

class SouthParent(Parent):

    shirt_color = 'white'
    shoes_color = 'blue'


SouthParent.external_class.foo()
# something
```